# Can I take the drive out of my Ubuntu laptop, put it in my Windows laptop, and seamlessly use it through wsl?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I had an old work laptop running Ubuntu and I got to keep the HDD after leaving. My current laptop runs Win 11 and I added the old Ubuntu disk into the spare HDD slot. I got WSL and was able to mount the disk so I can view my Linux filesystem. But I can't run any of my packages I had originally installed. Its like WSL gives me a fresh install of ubuntu and I can look at my files, but what I want is to run ubuntu off of the HDD. I want it to feel like I just opened my old laptop and nothing has changed- all the same applications, customizations, personalizations, shortcuts, etc... Is that possible? If not, what is my best alternative?

Comment: Yes, WSL is an installation by itself. No you can't turn your bare metal installation from another machine into a WSL instance.

Comment: What you can do, assuming your old laptop had UEFI and Ubuntu was installed in UEFI mode, is to try using Boot Repair to (re)install Grub, now in the main drive's EFI partition and then setup a dual-boot. That said there are caveats and a lot that can go wrong.

Comment: Are the laptops *exactly* the same model, with the same hardware? If not, you likely could not even run **directly** from that HDD, much less in WSL or a VM, on a different PC -- drivers and settings would be inappropriate.

Comment: Are you on Windows 10 or 11?  That (I think) will change the answer (somewhat).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds win11